# Object file not being created

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, g++

This is from Richard Stevens book on advanced Linux programming .

So when it teaches compiling with GCC,G++ , 
I created a folder named `reciprocal` , in which the following files were created with code shown below.

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "reciprocal.hpp"
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;
  i = atoi (argv[1]);
  printf ("The reciprocal of %d is %g\n", i, reciprocal (i));
  return 0;
}
```

`reciprocal.cpp`:

```
#include <cassert>
#include "reciprocal.hpp"
double reciprocal (int i) {
  // I should be non-zero.
  assert (i != 0);
  return 1.0/i;
}
```

`reciprocal.hpp`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern double reciprocal (int i);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

All the three files are in the same folder . Now I typed the command in terminal `gcc -c main.c` and the object `main.o` was created but when I wrote `g++ -c reciprocal.cpp` it shows error

```
reciprocal.cpp: In function ‘double reciprocal(int)’:
reciprocal.cpp:4:8: error: redefinition of ‘double reciprocal(int)’
reciprocal.cpp:4:8: error: ‘double reciprocal(int)’ previously defined here
```

What is going wrong here ?

Comment: Why are you compiling reciprocal.cpp? main() should be defined for the file you are compiling. You don't have a main() for reciprocal.cpp

Comment: Works for `g++` 4.8.2. (After fix the `#endi` typo.) Which version of `g++` are you using?

Comment: thanks @leeduhem  I updated to g++ 4.8.2 and it worked :) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are compiling it as C++. Either compile it as C or dump the `extern "C"` bit

Comment: I don't know but somehow either of the options are not working , i compiled it as c , it didn't work then dumped the extern C , still showing the same error

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanted the following in reciprocal.cpp:

```
#include <cassert>
#include "reciprocal.hpp"
extern "C" double reciprocal (int i) {
  // I should be non-zero.
  assert (i != 0);
  return 1.0/i;
}
```

Also if you compile both files with the same language you will not need those `extern` clauses at all. So, you can create either main.cpp and reciprocal.cpp and compile them with g++, or main.c and reciprocal.c and compile them with gcc. The first case is giving a C++ project, second one a C project.

Answer (score 2):

Please add header guard in class reciprocal.h if it is not present, As you are including reciprocal.h twice in main.cpp and reciprocal.cpp you are facing this error.

```
 #ifndef RECIPROCAL_H
 #define RECIPROCAL_H
 // All code here
 #endif
```